# html script history.back() causes "Confirm Form Resubmission". How to suppress that browser prompt using my custom script?

Tags: javascript, browser-cache, back

I have a situation  when the user hits the browser back button, the user is first alerted for resubmission with **"Confirm Form Resubmission"** ... cache miss". I have no control on the way the page is requested I can't send no-cache on the request (like chrome does when we select "disable cache" on the devtools network tab).

I did try to inject a custom html button on the 2nd page (where the back is made)  that does the **window.history.back()** but it gets the very same result.

Is there a way to programatically tell the browser that it is ok to reload/repost that page?

note: I do not have control of the application code, only this two customizable html pages which invocations are controlled by the existing 3rd party platform

Thanks,
JD